# List of url-links with \href

Tags: hyperref, errors, lists, links

When trying to create a list of weblinks using

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}  

\begin{itemize}
\item \href{www.washingtonpost.com}
\item \href{www.newyorktimes.com}
\item \href{www.lemonde.fr}
\item \href{www.guardian.co.uk}
\item \href{www.spiegel.de}
\item \href{www.bbc.co.uk/news}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I run into an error stating `\pdfendlink cannot be used in vertical mode`. What is a better approach to achieve this, or how can I modify mine?

Comment: Use `\href{www.washingtonpost.com}{washington post}`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`\href` takes two arguments, `\href[options]{URL}{text}` where the first is a full URL and the second the link text, and formats the text as normal text (see http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf for details). So you can fix your problem by adding a full URL in the first argument and adding a second argument, i.e. `\href{http://www.washingtonpost.com}{www.washingtonpost.com}`.

But the easiest way to fix it may be to replace `\href` with `\url` which formats the URL in typewriter font (I've added the protocol for completeness):

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}  

\begin{itemize}
\item \url{http://www.washingtonpost.com}
\item \url{http://www.newyorktimes.com}
\item \url{http://www.lemonde.fr}
\item \url{http://www.guardian.co.uk}
\item \url{http://www.spiegel.de}
\item \url{http://www.bbc.co.uk/news}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, much quicker answer. You might want to add to your answer that `\href` formats the link as normal text, while `\url` uses a typewriter font.

Comment: @Jake Good point. Fixed.

Comment: @Jake: But one can change the appearence of the `\url`s via `\urlsytle{<option>}`

Comment: @Jake: It is possible to setup `\href` to format the link as typewriter font?

Comment: @BeniBogosel: I don't think `hyperref` has a configuration option for this, but you could define a new command like `\newcommand{\tthref}[2]{\href{#1}{\texttt{#2}}}`, which will take two arguments (like `\href`): `\tthref{<URL>}{<link text>}`.