# Undefined Control Sequence Problem

Tags: sharelatex

I have the following code:

```
\title{Improvement of the Cascadic Multigrid Algorithm with a Gauss Seidel 
Smoother to Efficiently Compute the Fiedler Vector of a Graph Laplacian}
\author{Shivam Gandhi \href{email: shivam.jgandhi@gmail.com}
   \and \href{Tufts University Department of Mathematics}}
\date{November 2015}
```

However, it is returning the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\@author ->Shivam Gandhi \href 
                               {email: shivam.jgandhi@gmail.com} \and \href ...
l.19 \maketitle

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I am using ShareLaTeX for writing the paper, so it may be the compiler. Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't `\href` take two arguments? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33282/list-of-url-links-with-href Also have you loaded the `hyperref` package?

Comment: No, I haven't loaded that package. Is \href primarily for linking websites? I may find something else to write out the author field

Comment: I believe `\href` is provided by the `hyperref` package, without that package it's undefined (hence your error message) and you can't use it, to the best of my knowledge. Which command you should use will depend on what you want to do, but the `hyperref` package seems to provide lots of good options (haven't really used it myself, though)

Comment: Okay. I tried adding the hyperref package and received a series of errors, so I will try to solve the situation in some other way.

Comment: Please provide a MWE, so that someone can help you.

Comment: @Au101: Yes, `\href` _is_ provided by the __hyperref__ package! :-)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I finally submitted my first research paper!

Answer (score 3):

You may want something like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\title{Improvement of the Cascadic Multigrid Algorithm with a Gauss Seidel 
Smoother to Efficiently Compute the Fiedler Vector of a Graph Laplacian}
\author{Shivam Gandhi
  \href{mailto:shivam.jgandhi@gmail.com}{shivam.jgandhi@gmail.com}
  \and \href{http://math.tufts.edu/}{Tufts University Department of Mathematics}}
\date{November 2015}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or: `\href{mailto:shivam.jgandhi@gmail.com}{\nolinkurl{shivam.jgandhi@gmail.com}}`, depending on your taste…

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I finally submitted my first research paper!