# Automatically generate list of links in a document (similar to list of figures etc.)

Tags: hyperref, automation

Suppose you have a document containing lots of links but hidden under description text generated via `hyperref`. In a electronic version of the document you can just click on the link, but if you have only a printed version you cannot see the actual url. So it would be nice to add a list of hyperlinks contained in the document at the end of the document similar to a list of figures or tables, such that a reader having only a printed copy knows the urls refered to in the text. Maybe one could include also qr-codes in the link list. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[short labels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}


\section*{Automatically generated link list}
\subsection*{Some text}

On \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33282/list-of-url-links-with-href}{TeX Stackexchange} you can find nice questions to nice answers about \href{http://www.tug.org/}{\TeX}  and \href{https://www.latex-project.org/}{\LaTeX}.

\subsection*{List of links}

TODO: This is what the question is about
%% \makelistoflinks

\vspace*{1ex}
\hrule
\vspace*{1ex}

\section*{How it should look like}

\subsection*{Some text}

On \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33282/list-of-url-links-with-href}{TeX Stackexchange} [L1] you can find nice questions to nice answers about \href{http://www.tug.org/}{\TeX} [L2] and \href{https://www.latex-project.org/}{\LaTeX} [L3].

\subsection*{List of links}

\begin{enumerate}[L1]
\item \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33282/list-of-url-links-with-href}
\item 
\url{http://www.tug.org/}
\item
\url{https://www.latex-project.org/}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not sure of how to reference the links from the text to the link lists. I used `[L1]` etc. in the text as label but maybe a little supscript would be less distracting. So the solution should be configurable in that aspect. Maybe you have also another idea of how to reference it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the time to think about references and so on, but you can store and retrieve the links like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N\g_student_list_of_links_seq
\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \catcode`\$=6 %
  \catcode`\#=12 %
  \gdef\href@$1{\seq_gput_right:Nn \g_student_list_of_links_seq {$1}\expandafter\href@split$1##\\}%
  \gdef\href@split$1#$2#$3\\$4{%
    \hyper@@link{$1}{$2}{$4}%
    \endgroup
  }%
\endgroup  
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33282/list-of-url-links-with-href}{TeX Stackexchange} you can find nice questions to nice answers about \href{http://www.tug.org/}{\TeX}  and \href{https://www.latex-project.org/}{\LaTeX}.


\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_map_inline:Nn \g_student_list_of_links_seq {\url{#1}\par}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you should add `\usepackage{expl3}` to your example.

Comment: That's not needed with a current LaTeX.